# DI Error in my new Webpack application

Tags: angular, webpack

I just updated my Angular 2 application to be using Webpack for the minification, so I had to make many structure changes but I thought I was now good.

I actually have many levels on the application for the modules, like this :

- app (with some components at this level like login)

  - Admin (with several components like homepage, users)
  - Demo (with components like registration)

So I have for each module a routing module. For app it works, I land on the login page by default and everything works as expected, its route is like :

```
            {
                path: 'login',
                component: LoginComponent,
                data: {
                    name: 'login'
                }
            },
```

But if I want to go on some components from the other modules, like when I login, I'm supposed to go to /admin which makes me go on the HomepageComponent in the AdminModule which is set like that in the app routing module :

```
            {
                path: 'admin',
                loadChildren: () => new Promise(resolve => {
                                                  (require as any).ensure([], require => {
                                                      resolve(require('./admin/admin.module').AdminModule)
                                                  })
                                              })
            },
```

But when I land on another module I get this error :

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: DI Error

at NoProviderError.ZoneAwareError (zone.js:811)

at NoProviderError.BaseError [as constructor] (errors.js:25)

at NoProviderError.AbstractProviderError [as constructor] (reflective_errors.js:64)

at new NoProviderError (reflective_errors.js:126)

at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (reflective_injector.js:492)

at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (reflective_injector.js:531)

at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (reflective_injector.js:463)

at ReflectiveInjector_.get (reflective_injector.js:332)

at AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get (ng_module_factory.js:146)

at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.injectorGet (view.js:165)

at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.injectorGet (view.js:593)

at ElementInjector.get (element_injector.js:34)

at AdminModuleInjector.get (/AdminModule/module.ngfactory.js:216)

at AdminModuleInjector.get (/AdminModule/module.ngfactory.js:221)

at AdminModuleInjector.getInternal (/AdminModule/module.ngfactory.js:306)
```

I definitely have no idea what can be wrong here. Have you any lead on why it could happen?

Comment: I'd like to also add that the services classes used in components are always in the module providers then put in the component constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, somehow an external library service had to be included in the app module providers, but it was working before without doing it.